# .NET5 Disable copying of references

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

I'm working with a plugin framework built on .NET5 ASP.NET. Plugins are compiled as class libraries - that of which references other class libraries.

Whenever I compile, all the referenced class libraries, nuget packages, and the core asp.net .dlls are copied to the ref and refs folder. How do I disable this behavior?

I've already **Copy Local** and **Copy Local Satellite Assemblies**  to **No**, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Liaoo, The referenced packages or other class libraries are required when compile. Why do you want to disable copying of reference?

Comment: Hi @Rena,

Class libraries are plugins that are stored in a sub directory of the application. Since the main application already has the asp.net assemblies, no point in having them in the plugins as well